# How to convert from one header pin diameter to another?

Tags: gauge, jumper

I've unfortunately/accidentally purchased some 2.54 mm-pitch [headers](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32993269493.html) with pin-diameter **0.5 mm** -- significantly thinner than the common DuPont cables with pin-diameter **0.64 mm**. *(When ordering them, I only paid attention to the pitch, I didn't realize there was significant variation in pin-diameter for this common form factor.)*

I've only now discovered my error after soldering the headers to a board, and found that the male DuPont cables refuse to fit. I'm reluctant to de-solder the headers to avoid ruining the board.

What are my options here? For instance, are there any simple cables, that convert from one header pin-size to another?

(I'm not asking for specific product recommendations (though I'd not reject them), all I need to know is what to look for.)

Comment: Learn to desolder.  Get a solder pump (solder sucker).  Cut the plastic of the header, and remove the pins one by one.

Comment: This isn't related to wire gauge; pin sizes are never specified in AWG, always by linear dimensions in my experience. The most common size is 0.025" square pins, which corresponds to the 0.64 mm you mention.

Comment: @Hearth Not sure what you're talking about? There is rather direct relationship between a pin's diameter, its cross-sectional area, and that of any cables that will be inserted into/over the pin. Besides, I only used AWG since that's the most common measure I found in discussion threads ...

Comment: @SoreDakeNoKoto Are you talking about *sockets*? Nothing gets inserted *into* a pin, pins are inserted into things.

Comment: @Hearth Hence, the word "over" in my comment. And I do mean both pins and sockets -- this distinction is irrelevant here, the pin and socket diameters are roughly the same for a matching pair of male & female headers, and I happen to have purchased both. I'm (ideally) looking to know if there are jumpers with 0.5 mm (24 AWG) on one end and 0.64 mm (28 AWG) on the other, whether pins or sockets.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Little to do with learning, more to do with effort and available equipment. If you have any useful solutions, please leave an answer.

Comment: @SoreDakeNoKoto  A [solder sucker](https://www.jameco.com/z/HB-017-Jameco-BenchPro-High-Vacuum-Manual-Desolder-Pump-with-PTFE-Tip_1942139.html) and a soldering iron it all equipment you need for desoldering thoughole.

Comment: @SoreDakeNoKoto And I'm saying talking about wire gauge isn't going to help you find answers, because you're talking about pin sizes, which are not related to wire gauges. Yes, if they're jumper wires you can talk about the gauge of the wire they're attached to, but you can put a 25 mil pin on a 36 AWG wire or on a 12 AWG wire and it's still a 25 mil pin. And yes, you can calculate an equivalent wire gauge, but no one talks about pin and socket connectors in terms of wire gauge, just in terms of pin dimensions and pitch.

Comment: Your link shows a set of plugs and sockets. If that is what you got, why not use those plugs instead of the 'DuPont' plugs?

Comment: @BruceAbbott (If I understood you correctly) You're suggesting I use these odd 0.5 mm headers on both ends of the jumper connection. Problem is, even if I were willing to propagate these 0.5 mm headers across new boards, I have existing dev-boards and modules which are far more likely to use 0.64 mm pin-size. I'll still need a way to adapt/convert between them :(

Comment: @Hearth I've the feeling there are no good solutions left here but if it clarifies things and helps to get an answer, then sure, I'll edit the question and remove the AWG mentions.

Comment: Well what answer you would be happy with? Why not add and solder correct size pin headers to the incorrect ones?

Comment: @Justme That's exactly the sort of answer I'm looking for, from someone who can say it authoritatively enough -- that there's really no cable converters, that there are no other sensible options, but to simply de-solder the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'correct' solution is to remove the turned-pin socket strips and replace them with 'Dupont' compatible female header strips like this:-

[Würth Elektronik 61301011821 CONN HDR 10POS 0.1 GOLD PCB](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/61301011821/2508628)

[image]

If you don't want to remove the existing sockets then you can plug these headers into them (yes, they do fit). To make sure they stay on you could apply some hot-melt glue on the outside where they meet the turned pin sockets.

Alternatively you could make adapters by soldering these onto the turned-pin plugs you got with the turned-pin sockets, or perhaps solder some Dupont cables directly onto the turned-pin plugs (I often do this when I want to plug into IC sockets, which are too small to take Dupont plugs without being damaged).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resolve, buy the board to wire connector mating with your wrong purchase, and the wire to wire connector mating with the .64 Dupont, and build an adapter.